# Excel wildcard not working

Tags: excel, wildcard, countif

My situation:
Newly installed Excel.

Table:

```
A |  BS 
A | SDC
A | BS f
A | BS c
B | SDC
B | TIP
B | SDC
C | BS s
C | SDC
D | BS a
E | SDC
```

[image: theTable]

My need: I need to count all the BS* ones.

My formula: `=COUNTIF(B1:B11; "BS*")`
The result shows 0. Always. I have tried with other tables. 
`=COUNTIF(B1:B11; "BS")` returns 1 of course.
But I need `BS*`

I have tried other wildcards in other situations. And none are working. Do I have to turn something on in Excel first?

Hope you can help

Comment: **`=COUNTIF(B1:B11,"BS*")`** is working for me based on your test data.

Comment: could it be as simple as pressing F9 ?

Comment: Trying it at home as well, is working as you said. Just not on work-computer. That is why I asked if there is something I have to turn on? Will try F9 tomorrow ^^

Answer (score 0):

From the [Microsoft page on COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34):

```
Make sure your data doesn't contain erroneous characters.

When counting text values, make sure the data doesn't contain leading spaces,
trailing spaces, inconsistent use of straight and curly quotation marks, or
nonprinting characters. In these cases, COUNTIF might return an unexpected
value.
```

I recreated your error by copying your values from the question, but when I took out the leading spaces using (TRIM) it gave the right results.

Comment: Will try that tomorrow at work. I'll keep you informed. Tnx. ^^

Answer (score -2):

The way Excel implements the * wildcard is fundamentally wrong, in my opinion. The * should be any characters, including no characters. But it will not see "no characters". So if you have the data (text): 747, 747-100, 747-200 the formula COUNTIF(range,"747*") will return 2, instead of 3. That's WRONG.